# Why does Auto detect otp is not rendering the code in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, one-time-password

I am using auto detect otp in my application using [web-otp documentation](https://web.dev/web-otp/) . I have used bleow code in my application

```
        otprenderGetMobile() {
                const{ otpValue}=this.props;
                let signal = new AbortController();
        
                setTimeout(() => {
                    // abort after 10 minutes
                    signal.abort();
                }, 10 * 60 * 1000);
        
                let { code, type } = navigator.credentials.get({
                    abort: signal,
                    otp: {
                        transport: ["sms"]
                    }
                }).then(otp=>{
                alert('otp value is: ',JSON.stringify(otp));
                alert('code value is: ',JSON.stringify(code));
                alert('type value is: ',JSON.stringify(type));
                    otpValue = otp;
                });
            }
```

my htm is

```
<input
  type="text"
  id="otp"
  name="otp"
  autocomplete="one-time-code"
/>
```

my OTP Message format is

```
3052 is your Myapp verification code

@dev.myapp.com #3052
```

its working fine on android device but the problem is when I allow the device permission the otp does not prompts in the application.
I have attached the images of android outputs
[image]

> here are the outputs after i allow browser access

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: from where did you call this function otprenderGetMobile , for me after clicking on "allow", otp is not getting copied in the field. Im calling the above method from useEffect(()=>otprendermethod,[]) Please help me

Comment: pleae help me with the above comment, I will upvote the given answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by just replacing the below code

```
 let { code, type } = navigator.credentials.get({
                    abort: signal,
                    otp: {
                        transport: ["sms"]
                    }
                }).then(otp=>{
                alert('otp value is: ',JSON.stringify(otp));
                alert('code value is: ',JSON.stringify(code));
                alert('type value is: ',JSON.stringify(type));
                    otpValue = otp;
                });
```

with this

```
 navigator.credentials.get({
                otp: { transport: ['sms'] },
                signal: ac.signal
            }).then(otp => {
               console.log('your otp code is',otp.code)
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in the jsx component

```
<input
  type="text"
  autocomplete="one-time-code"
/>
```

resource https://www.twilio.com/blog/html-attributes-two-factor-authentication-autocomplete

Comment: i am using the same. **autocomplete="one-time-code"** is used to query textbox to set the **code** value ! this is not the problem. the problem is **navigator.credentials.get()** method should return the otp, but for some reason its not returning any value.